# Conversion from seconds to minutes in a dataframe

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with two columns, `ID` and `BillableDuration` (in seconds)

```
 ID    BillableDuration
 1       140
 2       35
 3       543
 4       200
```

I wanted to convert this convert the values in `BillableDuration` in minutes, I used the following:

```
library(lubridate)

BillableDuration_seconds<- period_to_seconds(hms(df$BillableDuration))

BillableDuration_mins <- BillableDuration_seconds/60;

new_df <- cbind(df, BillableDuration_mins)
```

Expected Output:

```
 ID    BillableDuration    BillableDuration_mins
 1       140               2.33
 2       35                0.58
 3       543               9.05
 4       200               3.33
```

But i got the following error:

> Warning message:In .parse_hms(..., order = "HMS", quiet = quiet) :
>         Some strings failed to parse

What I am doing wrong here, is there a better method to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was already using the library "lubridate", I thought of using this, your suggestion is good

Comment: perhaps `as.numeric(df$BillableDuration)/60`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can divide the second column by 60

```
 df1$BillableDuration_mins <- df1$BillableDuration/60
```

Comment: Just a quick question, can you improve the answer where I refer the column name

Comment: @user3875610  Thanks, replaced by the column name.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Akrun, you have always answered my questions :-)